# How can I enable star rating in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, ratings

How to enable Star rating in Magento2?
Currently Customers can only write "reviews" but cant rate the product..

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 23):

You have to enable  ratings from Admin Panel.

> Stores -> Attributes -> Rating

**Click on Price, Value, Quality Row and Checked Is Enable Checkbox from page and also set Visibility for your required store.**

Save Rating and your ratings are display.

Clear cache and check in product details page.

Screenshot for ratings,
[image]

Comment: For those on the hunt like I was: these can wind up being disabled if you switch your Single Store Mode.