# Programatically get product rating and review in magento 2 product collection

Tags: magento2, product-collection, review, ratings, product-review

How can programatically get product rating and review in product collection in **Magento 2**.

Comment: first to set enable rating from admin side
[here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143187/how-can-i-enable-star-rating-in-magento2)

Comment: it  was already enabled..i want to get the rating programatically

Comment: please confirm whether you are looking for ratnigs and reviews collection by using sku

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the **product object** and get the rating summary for specific product.

```
protected $_reviewFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_reviewFactory = $reviewFactory;
    ...
}

public function getRatingSummary()
{
    ...
    $this->_reviewFactory->create()->getEntitySummary($product, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());

    return $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
}
```

Comment: i got the product rating...but how can i get the product review by customers..?

Answer (score 0):

> You can use below code to get products reviews and rating summary

```
$sku = 'test-product';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create("Magento\Catalog\Model\Product")->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku); //use load($producID)
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currentStoreId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();
```

**Rating summary**

```
$reviewFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Review');
$reviewFactory->getEntitySummary($product, $currentStoreId);    
$ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
```

**Reviews**

```
$review = $objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory");

$collection = $review->create()->addStoreFilter(
            $currentStoreId
        )->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
        )->addEntityFilter(
            'product',
            $product->getId()
        )->setDateOrder();

print_r($collection->getData());
```